# last-child selector - issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css-selectors

I am using the last-child selector to pad out a gap in my nav bar and it all works fine in most browsers, except in the latest version of IE. Are there any solutions or fallbacks for this?

```
ul.dropdown li:last-child{padding-right:20px}
```

html:

```
<nav id="main-navigation">

        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Digital Printing      <span><span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Bureau Services</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Variable Data</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Large Format</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Email & SMS Broadcasting</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Data List Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Campaign Planning</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Email Build</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Broadcast</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Track & Learn</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mailing & Fulfilment</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Direct Mail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fulfilment</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Postal Services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Consultancy</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Print Management</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Cross Media Services</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Stragety Execution</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The msdn site says , last-child selector is  [available and works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE9.
But as you know, IE uses a  [different box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) .

Maybe this cause the problem. Try to add an ie-specific line with margin :

```
ul.dropdown li:last-child{padding-right:20px; margin-right:20px\0/IE9;}
```

Comment: Can you show me the html code too? I'd like to "play" with it.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and IE8 don't support last-child, but they do support first-child. Just gotta switch the coding around to change the first one instead of the last one.

Comment: the latest version of IE is not IE7 or 8. It's IE9.